# polynomial time reduction from SIS to decisional-LWE?

Tags: lwe, sis, reduction

Is the claim "If there is an efficient algorithm that solves SIS, then there is an efficient algorithm that solves decisional LWE" is sufficient?
or,
Is the claim above is equivalent to the fact that an instance of SIS is a polynomial-time reduction to an instance of decisional LWE?

Please suggest an answer with suitable references (if possible).

Comment: can I contact you in private?